# derbysqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception cause a violation of foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, user-interface, netbeans, datatables

I am using netbeans to create a gui. I created two tables, PETOWNER and ANIMALREG where the primary key of table PETOWNER is PETOWNERNIC and is also the foreign key of table ANIMALREG.  Now when i have to insert a record in table ANIMALREG i get an error:
derbysqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception: INSERT on table 'ANIMALREG' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'SQLxxx' for key(). The statement has been rolled back. Here's my table of PETOWNER:

```js
CREATE TABLE "PETOWNER" (
"PETOWNERNIC" varchar(14) NOT NULL,
"FIRSTNAME" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"LASTNAME" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
"ADDRESS1" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"ADDRESS2" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"ADDRESS3" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"PHONE" varchar(8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("PETOWNERNIC")
);
```

This is my table for ANIMALREG:

```js
CREATE TABLE "ANIMALREG" (
"PETID" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
"PETNAME" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
"PETOWNERNIC" VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
"BREED" VARCHAR(30),
"SEX" VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
"DOB" VARCHAR(10),
"WEIGHT" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
"VACCINE" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("PETID"),
FOREIGN KEY ("PETOWNERNIC") REFERENCES 
"PETOWNER"("PETOWNERNIC")
);
```

And my code where i can insert a new record:

```js
private void addNewPetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // To insert a new pet record
        try{
            String sqlInsertpet = "insert into ANIMALREG (PETID, PETNAME,PETOWNERNIC, BREED,SEX,DOB,WEIGHT, VACCINE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlInsertpet);
            ps.setString(1, PetIDTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(2, PetNameTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(3, PetOwnerNicTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(4, PetBreedTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(5, PetSexTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(6, PetDobTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(7, PetWeightTxt.getText());
            ps.setString(8, PetVaccineTxt.getText());
            ps.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Pet added !!\nSuccess");
            updatePetTable();
            PetIDTxt.setText("");
            PetNameTxt.setText("");
            PetOwnerNicTxt.setText("");
            PetBreedTxt.setText("");
            PetSexTxt.setText("");
            PetDobTxt.setText("");
            PetWeightTxt.setText("");
            PetVaccineTxt.setText("");
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert New Pet Error: "+e);
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what i am missing?

Comment: Presumably the owner value in the animal record doesn’t match a record in the owner table

Comment: No i put the same value for both record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it myself. My code are well written. I made a mistake in variable name where i used the variable name of table PETOWNER in my code to insert a new pet record.

Comment: Hi! I'm glad that you managed to solve your problem. Dont forget to accept your answer so we can know that this question is resolved. Thanks!